# How do I call a method that takes in an int array in java?

Tags: java

For example, the code would be similar to:

```
public static int test(int arr[], int x, int y){
       x = y;
       arr[y] = 1;
       return y;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
       test();
}
```

what would i put in test() in the main method? for int x and int y i just put a number but for arr[] I'm not sure what i'm supposed to put in? I want the array to be like {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} but I tried test({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, 1, 1) and it's not working.

Comment: Do you want to use methods/functions to set an array from 1 to 9?

Comment: `new int[] {1, 2, ...}`

Comment: To call a method from the main method using array as parameter we just call like this  function_name(array_name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply declare your array separately and then pass it inside your method. No stress!

```
//Your method:
public static int test(int arr[], int x, int y){
   x = y;
   arr[y] = 1;
   return y;
}

//main method:
public static void main(String[] args){
   int[] someArray = {1, 2, 5, 12, 2};
   test(someArray, 4, 5);
}
```

You can also pass in a pre-initialized array object like this:

```
//main method:
public static void main(String[] args){
   test(new int[]{1, 2, 5, 12, 2}, 4, 5);
}
```

Although, I hope that's not the actual content of your test() method [The body is erroneous.. *my illustration just shows hot to pass an array inside a method*].

Merry coding!

Answer (score 1):

From what I managed to decipher I think you wanted something like this:

```
//Main method:
public static void main(String[] args) 
{    

    int[] arr = new int[9];
    //x is the number we start counting up from
    //y is the number of elements we want to change
    arr = setArray(arr, 0, 9);

    //Print the array after we're done setting it up with the setArray function
    for(int i: arr) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }


}

    //setArray takes in an integer array and 2 integers
    //the array is arr from the public class, the x and y are explained in the main method above^

    //Custom method:
    public static int[] setArray(int[] array, int x, int y) {
    for(int i=x; i<y; i++) {
        array[i] = i+1;
    }
    return array;

}
```

Comment: Yeah the real code is rather long so I just used something random, I figured people didn't want to go through too many irrelevant lines of code for no reason since the code itself doesn't matter. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

To call a method from the main method just follow like that
**function_name(array_name)**
and if you want to return array from the function then do like that

```
public static int [] function_name(int array_name)
{
........
return array_name;
}
```